# How find this $I=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}t\sin{(\sqrt{x^2-t^2})}dt}{x^3}$

Tags: limits

find the limit

> $$I=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x^2}t\sin{(\sqrt{x^2-t^2})}dt}{x^3}$$

This problem I have three  idea:

> $$I=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x^2}t\sin{(\sqrt{x^2-t^2})}dt}{x^3}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin{(\sqrt{x^2-t^2})}d(x^2-t^2)}{x^3}$$
>
> **(1):**
> let $x^2-t^2=u$
> then
> $$I=-\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\sin{\sqrt{u}}du}{x^3}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\sin{x}\cdot 2x}{3x^2}=-\dfrac{1}{3}$$

**(2):**

> let $x^2-t^2=u$,then
> $$I=-\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\int_{x^2}^{0}\sin{\sqrt{u}}du}{x^3}=\cdots=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

**(3):**

> let $x^2-t^2=u$ then
> $$I=-\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\int_{x^2}^{x^2-x^4}\sin{\sqrt{u}}du}{x^3}=\cdots=0$$

**My question**,which is true? why? if this three idea is all not true,How can solution true methods? Thank you

Comment: The Maple command $$limit((int(t*sin(sqrt(-t^2+x^2)), t = 0 .. x^2))/x^3, x = 0, right) $$ produces 0. Also $$eval((int(t*sin(sqrt(-t^2+x^2)), t = 0 .. x^2))/x^3, x = 0.1e-1) $$ gives $0.00005000000000 .$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can brutally estimate $0 \leqslant \sin \sqrt{x^2-t^2} \leqslant 1$ (for $0 < x < 1$, say). Then

$$0 < \int_0^{x^2} t\sin\sqrt{x^2-t^2}\,dt < \int_0^{x^2} t\,dt = \frac12x^4,$$

from which we conclude

$$0 < \frac{\int_0^{x^2} t\sin\sqrt{x^2-t^2}\,dt}{x^3} < \frac12 x$$

for $0 < x < 1$, hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: so you mean my problem is $0$? and the tree idea is true? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think the substitution $t=ux^2$ is the simplest, it takes $x$ out of the integration limit and shows the integrand clearly vanishes in the limit so the answer is zero:$$\int _{0}^{{x}^{2}}\!{\frac {t\sin \left( \sqrt {{x}^{2}-{t}^{2}}
 \right) }{{x}^{3}}}{dt}=\int _{0}^{1}\!ux\sin \left( \sqrt {{x}^{2}-{
u}^{2}{x}^{4}} \right) {du}$$